# jQuery events... how much code should go inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-events

If I am attaching change events to a lot of items, say every checkbox on a large form, and then processing rules based on that, should I execute a separate function instead of having that code in an anonymous function inside the event?

```
$(".magic_checkbox").change(function(event){
  //somewhat lengthy code here
});
```

Is this creating a separate JavaScript function object for every checkbox, or are they all going to use one pointer? If they are all duplicates, will that even matter in the grand scheme of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one anonymous function, but you may want to consider delegated event approach.  Create a single event handler on a parent object of the `.magic_checkbox` elements.  Then do the following:

```
$("#parentObjectId").on("change", ".magic_checkbox", function(event){
    // your somewhat lengthy code here
});
```

or ...

```
$("#parentObjectId").on("change", ".magic_checkbox", function(event){
    somewhatLengthyMethod();
});

function somewhatLengthyMethod() {
    // your somewhat lengthy code here
}
```

Choosing between the two is just a matter of preference.  The key is event delegation which results in far fewer event handlers, hence more efficient.

Comment: Rather than `$("#parentObjectId").on("change", ".magic_checkbox", function(event) { somewhatLengthyMethod(); });`, `$("#parentObjectId").on("change", ".magic_checkbox", somewhatLengthyMethod);` might be preferable.

Comment: @icktoofay, true.  I like it!